# Proof that solvable permutation group whose fixed point set is restricted contains regular normal subgroup or Frobenius group on orbits

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, group-actions

> Let $p$ be a prime. Let $G$ be a solvable, non-regular, transitive permutation group such that some element fixes no point, and each element fixing some point fixes exactly $p$ points. Suppose that for $g \notin N_G(G_{\alpha})$ we have
>   $$
>  G_{\alpha}^g \cap G_{\alpha} = 1
> $$
>   and that $p$ does not divide the order of $G_{\alpha}$. Then $G$ has a regular normal subgroup $R$ or $G$ has an intransitive normal subgroup $F$ of index $p$ which acts as a Frobenius group on its $p$ orbits.

*Proof:* Let $G$ be a counter-example of minimal order. Let $N$ be an elementary abelian normal subgroup of $G$. As $N_{\alpha} \le G_{\alpha}$, but $p$ does not divide the order of $G_{\alpha}$ we have $N_{\alpha} = 1$, i.e. $N$ acts semi-regularly on $\Omega$. Since $G$ is a counter-example, $N$ is not transitive. Let $\Sigma$ be the orbits of $N$, and let $\Delta$ be the orbit containing $\alpha$. Then $G/N$ acts on the set $\Sigma$ and $G_{\alpha}N / N$ is the stabilizer of $\Delta$. 
Let $\overline \alpha$ be the set of fixed points of $G_{\alpha}$. Since $G$ acts transitive, the size of each block divides the order of $G$, and hence $\overline \alpha$ is a minimal $G$-block. Also since the orbits of $N$ are $G$-blocks, we have that either $\Delta \cap \overline \alpha = \overline \alpha$ or $\Delta \cap \overline \alpha = \{\alpha\}$.

Let $g \in G_{\alpha}$ and assume that $g$ fixes an orbits $\Delta'$ of $N$, i.e. $\langle g \rangle$ opertes on $\Delta'$. If $g$ would have no fixed point, then we would have by an orbit decomposition that $|\Delta'| = k\cdot o(g)$ for some $k$. But $|\Delta'| = |N|$, which is a $p$-group, and $o(g)$ does not divide $p$, so $g$ must have a fixed point in $\Delta'$ (which must come from $\overline a$). Hence if $\overline \alpha \subseteq \Delta$, $G / N$ acts as a Frobenious group on $\Delta$ and the action of $G/N$ on $\Sigma$ is faithful.

> I do not understand why $G/N$ acts as a Frobenious group, i.e. that it is non-regular and each $gN$ fixes at most one point. If $gN$ fixes some point, then this is equivalent to the statement that $g$ fixes some orbit $\Delta'$ of $N$, but in general we do not have $g \in G_{\alpha}$, so I do not see how the previous comments apply?

Let $R / N$ be the Frobenious kernel. Then $R$ acts regularly on $\Omega$, which is impossible.

> If $r \in R, r \ne 1$ would fix some $\beta^r = \beta$ and $\Delta'$ denotes the orbit of $N$ containing $\beta$, then as this is a block we would have $(\Delta')^r = \Delta'$, i.e. $rN$ fixes a point, which is not possible by definition of the kernel. So this is clear to me.

Therefore each of the orbits of $N$ contains at most one of the points of $\overline \alpha$ and $G / N$ acts in such a way that some element fixes no point, and each element fixing some point fixes exactly $p$ points.

> Here I do not understand why $G/N$ acts in that way?

If $|\Sigma| = p$ then $G$ would not be a counter-example.

> What condition is precisely violated so that this is not a counter-example?

Hence $|\Sigma| > p$ and $G/N$ acts faithfully on $\Sigma$. Therefore the assertion holds for $G/N$.

> I do not see why the point stabilizers are not divisible by $p$ and the intersection of different conjugates of the point stabilizers is trivial?

Again, if $R/N$ acts regularly on $\Sigma$ then $R$ acts regularly on $\Sigma$, which is impossible. Thus $G/N$ has an intransitive normal subgroup $F/N$ of index $p$ acting as a Frobenious group on its $p$ orbits. Each of the $p$ orbits of $F$ on $\Sigma$ contains exactly one of the points of $\overline \alpha$. Hence $F$ acts as a Frobenious group on $\Omega$, and we have a contradiction, proving the assertion. $\square$

I have some difficulty following the arguments in the proof. I have marked the parts I am unsure about. Maybe some additional remark, by saying $\overline \alpha$ is the set of fixed points of $G_{\alpha}$ we used the fact that each element from the point stabilizer has the same set of $p$ fixed points, i.e. the set $\overline \alpha$. This uses the assumption that different point stabilizers intersect trivial, I can supply a proof of this fact if wanted!

Comment: Just a minor comment: in several of your questions you have a transitive permutation group and you have assumed that some element fixes no point, But that is true of any transitive permutation group of degree greater than $1$, so there is no need to assume that!

Comment: I started looking through your proof, but I could not follow the third sentence in the proof. You don't know at this stage that $N$ is a $p$-group for your given prime $p$.

Comment: Regarding your first comment: Yes, that each transitive permutation group has a fixed point free element is a classical result by Jordan which I forgot by the moment, thanks for pointing out! For your second question, really that I asked myself too! This is the single other unclear point for me, but I choosed not to ask this to focus on the other points (I hoped that this point becomes clearer later as I started reading and learning about solvability, and I guessed it has something to do with solvability, as solvable groups contain elementary abelian normal subgroups for some $q$ (continue).

Comment: (cont.)This proof is from a paper: The way it really starts is: "Let $G$ be a counter-example of minimal order. Let $N$ be an elementary abelian normal subgroup of $G$. Then $N$ acts semi-regularly on $\Omega$, for otherwise we would have $p \mid |G_{\alpha}|$". I changed the wording a little bit because I hoped to make it clearer, but maybe I messed it up and have understood it wrongly; as you clearly said I do not see that we can choose $N$ for this specific prime, but I thought maybe it would be possible, but I do not understand why yet. That $N$ is semi-reg. maybe has another cause...

Comment: OK, I understand that now. The orbits of $N$ all have the same length and, since $N$ is abelian, $N$ acts regularly on each of its orbits. Now if $N_\alpha \ne 1$, then $N$ fixes exacly $p$ points (i.e. $\overline{\alpha}$), but then $\overline{\alpha}$ is a union of orbits of $N$, so $N$ is indeed a $p$-group, and their argument works.

Comment: For your first question, they have shown (or pointed out) that the stabilizer of $\Delta$ in $G/N$ is $G_\alpha N/N$, so we can choose $g$ such that $g \in G_\alpha$. That's all from me for now!

Comment: Just to make sure I got it right: As $N \unlhd G$ the orbits form a system of blocks, hence have all the same size. If $N$ fixes one point from an orbit, it fixes all points as $N$ is abelian, i.e. $\beta^N \le \mbox{fix}(N_{\beta})$. Now as $N_{\alpha}\le G_{\alpha}$ if $N_{\alpha} \ne 1$ each non-trivial element of this stabilizer fixes $\overline \alpha$. So that $\alpha^N \subseteq \mbox{fix}(N_{\alpha}) = \overline \alpha$. As $|\alpha^N|=1$ is excluded (faithful) and $p = |\overline\alpha|$ we have $|\alpha^N| = |N:N_{\alpha}|$, hence $p\mid |N|$.

Comment: For your other hint, I am not sure as this is just related to $\Delta$, but for a Frobenius group we must show that for arbitrary $\Delta', \Delta''$ we have $(G/N)_{\Delta'} \cap (G/N)_{\Delta''}$ is trivial, but here $\Delta$ is not involved, so I do not see how to incorporate the knowledge about the point stabilizer of $\Delta$ in $G/N$.

Comment: They have shown that any element of $G/N$ that fixes $\Delta$ fixes no other orbit in $\Sigma$, so it fixes a unique point.

Comment: That I see, but what has this to do with other orbits $\Delta' \ne \Delta$, here the point stabilizers also just have to fix a unique point, but I do not see that this is implied...

Comment: Before the construction goes it is fixed, it is choosen such that $\alpha\in \Delta$. And then if $\overline \alpha \subseteq \Delta$ it is shown that $G/N$ is a Frobeniuous group; maybe I read it wrongly? So if they write $\overline \alpha \subseteq \Delta$ they do not mean for the initially fixed $\alpha$ and $\Delta$, but that for every $\alpha$ and corresponding orbit $\Delta$ we have $\overline \alpha\subseteq \Delta$ (i.e. not just a single choosen one)?

Comment: Suppose $H$ is a transitive non-regular permutation group on a set $X$, and there exists $x \in X$ with the property that any element of $H$ that fixes $x$ fixes no other point of $X$. Then $H$ is a Frobenius group. Just apply this with $H=G/N$, $X=\Sigma$, and $x = \Delta$.

Comment: Okay, I see. If $H$ is as described and $\alpha \in X$ has the mentioned property, Then if $H_{\beta}\cap H_{\delta} \ne 1$, then choose $\beta^g = \alpha$, and we have $1 \ne (H_{\beta} \cap H_{\delta})^g = H_{\alpha} \cap H_{\delta^g}$, which is not possible. So $H$ is a Frobenious group.